# failed assertion `vertexFunction must not be nil - Error when loading a SceneKit scene in iPad iOS 9.0.2

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es, scenekit, metal

I am getting a frustrating error when testing my app on the iPad , at the moment my SCNScene gets loaded, as soon as I see the nodes on the screen. I got no idea what it could be:

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Metal/Metal-54.31/Framework/MTLRenderPipeline.mm:973: failed assertion `vertexFunction must not be nil.
```

I'm not directly using Metal, neither OpenGL, only SceneKit stuff. I don't understand much of them but I heard they are somehow used underneath.
I have tried to fix it by "forcing" OpenGL, as I did read in some topic that it could help:

```
scnView = GGBattleScene2(frame: view.frame, options: [SCNPreferredRenderingAPIKey : SCNRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2.rawValue])
```

The scene appeared, but a lot of elements added just got invisible, or not rendered, i don't know. Actually all of them with exception of the support axis I've drawn:

[image: axis visible]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found out this error only occurs because my SCNNodes have their materials set with a SKScene, with a SKSpriteNode inside of it. That itself is not a problem, since I've been running this in a earlier version of xCode and it worked perfectly. For some reason the compiler of the actual version makes something goes wrong there. I knew this because I used the same code in xcode 6.3.9 and it worked.

When I changed to set the material with the same texture used for the SKSpriteNode instead of the SKScene itself it worked

Comment: I have the same problem but I don't really understand your answer (sorry). How exactly did you change your texture? Did you directly use an image as the contents of a SCNMaterial instead of a SCNScene?

Comment: @DorianRoy, I used SKTexture (SKTexture(image:)) as the diffuse.contents property of my SCNMaterial

Comment: Ok. I need the SKScene to paint on it, so the texture alone won't do it. But right now I think I get this error because of a multithreading issue. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the similar bug and got the exact same console output:

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Metal/Metal-55.1.1/Framework/MTLRenderPipeline.mm:973: failed assertion `vertexFunction must not be nil.'
```

I check my project Scheme config and find the "Metal API Validation = Enabled" is the root cause. Disable it ("Metal API Validation = Disabled"), then the bug disappeared.

[image]

Comment: Omg, didn't notice this. Too bad I already made a huge workaround to avoid using SKScene, but thanks a lot. This might help me in the future!

Comment: Does not work for me... I'm using a SKVideoNode inside SceneKit